# Why does my linq to sql query fail?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am new to .Net (and stackoverflow) so I am running into a few problems. One vexing problem is this linq query below. Some information about the code. CustomerCart is a separate Model class in my project where the products member is a list of products. If I remove the products from the select new CustomerCart portion it runs fine and the data is present. So I figure it is my syntax. Can I not put a linq statement inside an assignment constructor? Any help would be appreciative. Thank you in advance.

```
var k = from s in store.Customers
        join p in store.ShoppingCarts on s.custId equals p.customerId
        select new CustomerCart()
        {
            FirstName = s.firstName,
            LastName = s.lastName,
            products = (from j in store.Products
                        where p.productId == j.productId
                        select j).ToList(),
            CartID = p.cartId,
            CustomerID = s.custId,
         };
```

**Edit
Error I receive: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[productShop.Models.CustomerCart]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'productShop.Models.CustomerCart'.

Sorry for not placing the error message with my question.

Comment: Does CustomerCart actually have a `products` property? All your other stuff is capitalized; are you sure its not `Products`?

Comment: i'm not sure that you can do a query in the projection. I would either include products in the join or do a foreach loop for k and populate the products in a second query.

Comment: Right if I remove the .ToList(), then it will not compile, it results in this error. Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<productShop.Models.Product>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<productShop.Models.Product>'. Also CustomerCart does have a products property lowercased so that portion is fine, I'll need to change so that it conforms. Thank you guys for the feedback I will try these suggestions.

Comment: @mryoyo - that error has nothing to do with your query.  That error is from MVC.  You are passing the wrong object to the view.  You are passing an `ObjectQuery<CustomerCart>` into your view, but your view needs a `CustomerCart`.  So you say `return View(k.FirstOrDefault());`  If you had included the error message originally, then you wouldn't have sent people down the wrong path of solving a problem that didn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query instead:

```
var k =
    from s in store.Customers
    join p in store.ShoppingCarts on s.custId equals p.customerId
    join j in store.Products on p.productId equals j.productId into products
    select new CustomerCart()
    {
        FirstName = s.firstName,
        LastName = s.lastName,
        products,
        CartID = p.cartId,
        CustomerID = s.custId,
     };
```

Comment: Using this I was able to solve the issue. Thank you very much, and thanks to everyone else who helped me out as well.